# Operator theory of initial-value ODE problems

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, unbounded-operators

The theory of elliptic boundary value problems is usually treated from the perspective of functional analysis, and the theory of operators between Hilbert spaces.

In contrast to that, the theory of ordinary differential equations subject to initial values is usually treated with tools from elementary analysis. But I would like to learn how to treat ODEs with initial values from the point of view of unbounded operators between Hilbert spaces.

As a motivation, consider the differential operator
 $\partial^2 : H^2([0,1]) \subset L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2([0,1])$

**A boundary value problem**

Suppose we restrict the domain to $H^2$-functions satisfying homogeneous boundary conditions. Then we obtain an elliptic differential operator:

$\partial^2 : H_0^2([0,1]) \subset L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2([0,1])$

So we can state the Poisson problem with Dirichlet boundary conditions:

Given $f \in L^2([0,1])$, find $u \in H^2([0,1])$ such that $\partial^2 u = f$, and $u(0) = u(1) = 0$ holds.

**An initial value problem**

Suppose we restrict the domain to $H^2$-functions satisfying whose zeroth and first derivative at $0$ vanish:

$\partial^2 : \{ u \in H_0^2([0,1]) : u(0) = u'(0) = 0 \} \subset L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2([0,1])$

I suppose that this provides the differential operator for solving the following initial value problem:

Given $f \in L^2([0,1])$, find $u \in H^2([0,1])$ such that $\partial^2 u = f$, and $u(0) = u'(0) = 0$ holds.

**Problem/Question:**

What is the correct approach to treat initial-value problems with unbounded operators? Note that I exclude semigroup theory here - I want it as close to the elliptic formulation as possible. What is the correct choice of the domain of the operator?

Furthermore, the proposed operator for the initial value problem is not self-adjoint, it is not even symmetric. Which nice properties can you use instead?

Comment: How do you get $\partial^2$ mapping from $H^2_0 \to H^2$? Shouldn't you lose regularity?

Comment: And in the IVP formulation, you probably do not want $u \in H_0^2$, since this presupposes that your solution vanishes at $1$, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: For ordinary differential equations you do not need to go to infinite dimensional vector spaces. It suffices to work with usual matrices. For partial differential evolution equations  there  you can look at Hille-Yosida theorem.

Comment: @WillieWong: Yes, this was a typo -.- i have corrected that.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: The point is that I want to circumvent the semigroup theory tools. I want it in a formulation as close to the elliptic theory as possible.